# Wrong line number in stack-trace in debugging Linux kernel using kgdb

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kgdb

I am trying to debug a driver for an **Ethernet-MAC** in the Linux kernel using **kgdb** over serial. 
I halt the execution by making a call to "`kgdb_breakpoint()`" at the desired location in the code and recompile the kernel.

But after the code halts, [as you may notice in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFBa7.jpg) the backtrace shows correct function-graph and source filenames but, for some reason corresponding line numbers are not correct.

Please note: I have compiled this kernel with "`CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER`" set and "`nokaslr`" in the boot-args.
Is there a way I can see a stack trace with correct line number here ? 
(I have used QtCreator during this screenshot, although behavior is similar with gdb over command-line or TUI)

Edit: No matter, whichever function I put the `kgdb_breakpoint()`
 in, (inside the driver source) , line number in the stacktrace always say the same line number for the halted function.

Comment: It means the binary you are running does not match the debugging information

Comment: I am booting the kernel over tftp and, the tftp server is configured to serve the uImage in arch/xxx/boot/ which is supposed to be updated on every build in along with executable image used with gdb.